# In POSIX.1, am I supposed to define types in multiple headers?

Tags: posix

I was reading the POSIX standard, and I found that it specifies that, for example, NULL be defined in stddef.h and in string.h. Am I supposed to define them? If so, how?

Comment: Are you implementing a posix subsystem, or are you using a posix-compliant subsystem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, POSIX is worded in such a way that including certain headers must make certain macro definitions and declarations available.  How the implementation achieves that is up to the implementation.  It is possible to duplicate the definitions and declarations in multiple header files, use separate header files for common items, or rely on C compiler magic to make them available.